# Chrome Network Preview Is Not Working

Tags: google-chrome

Suddenly chrome network preview has stopped working.

A few days back I could see the preview of the response of an API call. now preview tab displaying nothing for any API call.

I tried re-installing the chrome but same behavior.

[image]

[image].

Is there any setting to enable preview ??

My chrome version is 58.5.3029.81

Comment: I just encountered this now, after using it for years without problems. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @JanisJansen same 

Comment: @JanisJansen I did not get any solution until my system OS got reinstalled.

Answer (score -2):

Try to disable filter button and refresh page. Then make a request and check priview tab. This helped me.